What is the name of this episode of the Twilight Zone series (2002)
I remember seeing an episode of the Twilight Zone many years ago. In this episode there is a black man who just woke after decades of being in a coma thinking he is still a child and realizes he is actually an old man.
That's all I remember.
Could anyone help me to identify this episode?

According to this Yahoo Answers discussion, you could be talking about "Dorothy and Ben", which is an episode of Amazing Stories by Stephen Spielberg, not the Twilight Zone. Is this the one?

Exactly! Thank you very much!!! how did you find it?

I searched for "coma twilight zone" on Google.You're very welcome!
